# Java program draw a square using for loop?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Given:

```
public static void printTriangle(int sideLength) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= sideLength; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
            System.out.print("[]");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

How do you modify the code to print a square with sideLength = 3?

```
[][][]
[][][]
[][][]
```

Comment: Do you mean `System.out.println("sideLength("+sideLength+")");`

Comment: You want both loops `for (int i = 0; i < sideLength; i++)` do the same for `j`.

Comment: @Keppil `<=` will do one more than `<`

Comment: BTW I suggest you put the `{` at the end of the line as I do or on the next line as many others do, but I don't suggest you do both as you have. (i.e. pick one)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
public static void printSquare(int sideLength) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sideLength; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sideLength; j++) {
            System.out.print("[]");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```